# Unable to initialize SD card

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, sd-card

I am not able to initialize the SD card. Can't find figure out what the issue is. It fails at the condition

```
if (!SD.begin(D8)) {
Serial.println("initialization failed!");
return;
}
```

I am using D1 Mini V2 board and standard SD card module. Pin configuration attached with images below.
[image: Board]
[image: SD Module]

Connections are -

GND => GND

VCC => 3.3V

MISO => D6

MOSI => D7

SCK => D5

CS => D8

Code is -

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

File myFile;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  if (!SD.begin(D8)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");

  // open the file. note that only one file can be open at a time,
  // so you have to close this one before opening another.
  myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);

  // if the file opened okay, write to it:
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.print("Writing to test.txt...");
    myFile.println("testing 1, 2, 3.");
    // close the file:
    myFile.close();
    Serial.println("done.");
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }

  // re-open the file for reading:
  myFile = SD.open("test.txt");
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.println("test.txt:");

    // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
    while (myFile.available()) {
      Serial.write(myFile.read());
    }
    // close the file:
    myFile.close();
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // nothing happens after setup
}
```

Comment: Did you try different SD cards? (preferably smaller older ones, as SDXH for example might not work).

Comment: I am using Kingston microSD card

Comment: Is it not an SDHC or SDXH card? And did you try it with a default example?

Comment: The code copied above is the default example!

Comment: I expect the SD card is not supported than. I used a simpler SD card reader for the Uno and it could only read (old) upto 2 GB SD cards.

Comment: I myself am using 2gb card. Do you see any error in the code/connection?

Comment: this is a 5 V adapter. you have a 3.3 V board

Comment: Yep!!, that fixed it, changed VCC=> 5V and it solved the issue. Thanks @Juraj

Comment: but you don't need a logic level conversion between esp8266 and SD card adapter. https://i.stack.imgur.com/urotx.jpg

Comment: Use "SdFat" library.